Why does "#rarebeauty" -"#nike" not work in Google Custom Search when excluding hashtags?
I got the results all with "#nike"
I also tried to use excludeTerms and it also did not work, same thing that results will include #nike
I also tried to escape the # using \, but "#rarebeauty" -"#nike" returns very weird irrelavant results
Is there any solution? I expected results to exclude #nike, I could not find anything mentioning in the official doc: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list
